# Why do I get different results from Here Routing API and Here Maps Website?

Tags: here-api

We are using the Here Routing API v7.2 and cant get PT routing results for routes for which we can get results when using the same query on HERE Maps.

Examples:

This works:

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_code=LJXqQ8ErW71UsRUK3R33Ow&app_id=VgTVFr1a0ft1qGcLCVJ6&departure=2020-06-19T17%3A00%3A00&mode=fastest%3BpublicTransportTimeTable&waypoint0=geo%2152.51604%2C13.37691&waypoint1=geo%2153.55375%2C9.99183
```

This does not work:

```
https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=<API-KEY>&departure=2020-06-19T17%3A00%3A00&mode=fastest%3BpublicTransportTimeTable&waypoint0=geo%2152.51604%2C13.37691&waypoint1=geo%2153.55375%2C9.99183
```

Comment: Could you confirm your product type, are you using Freemium? From https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/public-transport-routing.html, publicTransportTimeTable "Note: This feature may be subject to premium pricing. For details, contact your HERE customer representative. "

Comment: Yes, we are using free plan.

Answer (score 0):

After checking with development team, `publicTransportTimeTable` mode should be enabled for Freemium plan. Internal ticket has been raised to track the issue. Any feedback from development team will be posted here when available.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I don't know if that's the right place for issue tracking, but I'll watch the thread and will try to give more debug info when needed.